# PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDE Select HTML tags in source code with CSS selector

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

Is it possible to evaluate CSS selector like XPath https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/xpath-search.html that would select multiple matching lines ?

Comment: could you clarify what kind of evaluation you have in mind? Note that you can use  [structural search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) to search for selectors

Comment: @lena : I would like to use normal CSS selector syntax to find tags I'm looking for instead of XPath. For example ```div.something > h1.heading | h2#myIdentifier```. Unfortunately I cannot find any HTML examples of structural search.

Comment: no, it's not possible. As for SSR examples, please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#examples-for-html-and-xml. There are also some predefined templates for XML/HTML